# How can I center the text within a <p> tag vertically?

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to center a <p> tag within its container, and while I have been able (using the top/translateY) trick to center the tag itself, the center of the text is not actually the center of the <p> tag's content, as seen here (the red line is the true middle of the tag):

[image]

How can I center the text in the <p> tag as well ?

Comment: if possible  provide  your Code

Comment: Probably because of the `line-height`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To center a `<p>` tag within its container, try to use a property of table.
Like, you have to set a property of parent container to `display:table` then set its child property to `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;`

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/SaurabhSonawane/sb7ko4wh/2/)

**Your Sample HTML should be like,**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <p>...... Your Text goes here .....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And relative CSS should be like,**

```
.parent {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    padding: 30px;
    display: table;
}

.child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

[For your reference check this out](http://howtocenterincss.com/)

Answer (score 4):

You can try to like this:

```css
p.myclass {
    font: bold 12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 10px;
    height:30px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
    bordeR: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<p class="myclass">test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vv3uy7vy/

Answer (score -1):

```
<p>Hi </p>

p{border:1px solid red; height:30px; line-height:30px;}
```

Assign the "height" of the container(here "p" tag) to line-height will make the content align vertically middle

Answer (score -2):

you and so the text in the middle. visually it seems less because you are using lowercase letters, while the height of the text is calculated by uppercase.

Comment: use this as comment